# Feedjira: Feed update returns duplicates

Tags: ruby, feed, feedjira

I am trying to print rss/atom feed updates using ruby. Feedjira seems to be the best bet for this. Unfortunately the update feature does not seem to work properly. I get duplicate entries.

Here is a simple example that produces the problem:

```
require 'feedjira'
require 'pp'

feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse "http://lorem-rss.herokuapp.com/feed?unit=second&interval=10"
loop do
    feed = Feedjira::Feed.update(feed)
    pp feed.new_entries
    sleep 20
end
```

Any suggestions? Maybe other libraries? Or am I missing something important when using Feedjira?

There a several questions around this topic for Feedzirra the former name for Feedjira, but the update feature seems to be a new feature: http://feedjira.com/updating-feeds.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated functionality was removed from feedjira due to serious problems. See

- (commit) https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/commit/6f56516934a9bdb8691f2bbe98be0f2b7c25b7ea
- (discussion) https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/issues/218